# How can I use the '@' symbol in an async Discord command function?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

how to have async function start with special character?

@client.command()
async def @everyone(ctx):
await ctx.reply('yea')

Whenever I command it doesnt work because the '@' messes up the syntax and doesn't see it as a viable function unless i had it without the '@', anyway for me to make it work out?

Comment: You can't, it's invalid syntax. Why would you need to have an '@' in your definition of an async function?

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood your question correctly, since your formatting is a bit off.

If you want special characters in your commands, you can use the `name` parameter in the command decorator, like so:

```py
@client.command(name="@everyone")
async def everyone(ctx):
    await ctx.reply('yea')
```